# Google Maps API v.3.31 update breaks StageWebView and StageWebViewBridge

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps-api-3, stagewebview, stagewebviewbridge

Google maps loaded via Flex/AS3/AIR HTML component, StageWebView, and StageWebViewBridge no longer display the standard map Markers and produces runtime errors.
Has anyone else noticed this? Solutions/workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the answer.
**Google Maps API v3.31** requires a better WebKit than the AIR WebKit which the Flex **HTML** component uses and which the **StageWebView** uses by default.
The WebKit cannot be changed in the FLEX HTML component (AIR WebKit) but the StageWebView component can be made to use the native browser's WebKit in its constructor:

```
var swv:StageWebView = new StageWebView(true); // pass 'true' for native browser's WebKit
```

To make this change in StageWebViewBridge you need to use the StageWebViewBridge project source code (https://github.com/xperiments/stagewebviewbridge) instead of the SWC and in the StageWebViewBridge class constructor, do the same thing:

```
super();
_autoUpdateProps = autoUpdateProps;
_viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 0, w, h );
_view = new StageWebView( true ); // pass 'true' for native browser's WebKit
_view.viewPort = _viewPort;
```